# Discrete Mathematics - In how many ways can $A$ and $B$ exchange their books?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$A$ has $5$ different books and $B$ has $3$ different books. How many ways are there in which they can exchange their books so that each keeps his individual number of books unchanged?

I got the answer as $55$, using combinations. Could you please tell me whether it is right, or point me in the right direction otherwise?

What if the question was the maximum possible ways in which they can be exchanged?? Is it P(5,3). Or Pow(5,3)..

Comment: How did you get to 55?

Comment: Do the indivuals exchangse matter? I explain : does "A exchange book $A_1$ for $B_1$ and $A_2$ for $B_2$" is the different from "A exchange book $A_1$ for $B_2$ and $A_2$ for $B_1$"? Cause the result is the same but the way is not the same.

Comment: C(5,3)*C(3,3)+C(5,2)*C(3,2)+C(5,1)*C(3,1)

Comment: Deuteu. It shouldn't matter I guess

Comment: @user3456936, really? Cause just by looking at my example in one case you have 1 way (with global) but considering single exchange, there is 2 ways. Where am I wrong in my thought?

Comment: @Deuteu I don't think he's saying "it doesn't matter how you interpret it, the answer is the same". He's actually answering you saying "It [individual exchange] doesn't matter".

Comment: @M.Vinay right, read too quickly

Comment: What if the question was the maximum possible ways in which they can be exchanged?? Is it P(5,3). Or Pow(5,3)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ exchange $1$ book, there are ${5\choose 1}\cdot {3\choose 1} = 15$ ways they can do this. If they exchange $2$ books, then there are ${5\choose 2}\cdot {3\choose 2} = 30$ ways to do this, and if they exchange $3$ books, there are ${5\choose 3}\cdot {3\choose 3} = 10$. All together, there are $15+30+10=55$ ways to do it. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

**Another approach:**
After any exchange, $A$ has to have $5$ books, and $B$ has to have (the remaining) $3$ books. So the result of an exchange is exactly the same as the result of selecting $5$ of the $8$ distinct books and giving them to $A$, and giving the remaining $3$ to $B$.
The number of ways of selecting $5$ books from $8$ distinct books is $\binom 8 5 = 56$.
Since they already have one such selection of books, the number of ways they can exchange them to get other selections is $56 - 1 = 55$.

**Alternative Interpretation:**
The question could be asking about the number of possible exchanges, where an exchange is defined as $\{A_i \leftrightarrow B_1, A_j \leftrightarrow B_2, A_k \leftrightarrow B_3 \}$, where $A_i$s and $B_p$s are the books currently with $A$ and $B$ (listed in some order). Then, as Deuteu was saying, $\{A_1 \leftrightarrow B_1, A_2 \leftrightarrow B_2, A_3 \leftrightarrow B_3\}$ is different from $\{A_1 \leftrightarrow B_2, A_2 \leftrightarrow B_1, A_3 \leftrightarrow B_3\}$.

The number of such exchanges is, of course, the number of ways of picking $A_i, A_j, A_k$ from $A_1, \ldots, A_5$, with understanding that $A_i$ is exchanged with $B_1$, then $A_j$ with $B_2$, and $A_k$ with $B_3$ (so the order matters). The answer is, therefore, $^5\text{P}_3 = 60$.

Comment: Beat me to it! :(

Comment: @OriaGruber YOU beat me to writing "beat you to it!". I just saw your answer and by the time I finished writing the comment, you deleted your answer and wrote this :P

Comment: You'd even written "Another approach:"!

Comment: Thank you guys. The professor got answer as 60 P(5,3) .

Comment: @user3456936 Did you mean he got the answer $60 = \text P(5, 3)$? Then you misinterpreted the question (or he did). I've updated my answer to include this case.